# mergext mergDataGridScroller droptools location

Tags: livecode

Downloaded mergDataGridScroller from the mergExt site today. In the readme it says that Sons of Thunder 'DropTools' is required. It doesn't say that on the main site. Plus, I cannot seem to find DropTools on the SOT site.

Comment: It would be possible to use it without DropTools but DropTools makes it a whole lot easier and is the only publicly available custom control framework around. All DropTools does is take the grunt work out of adding the control to your stack.

Answer (score 2):

You can download [DropTools](http://droptools.sonsothunder.com/); there is an explanation on [how to use it with mergDataGridScroller](http://mergext.com/forums/topic/how-to-add-mergdatagridscroller/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The signatures are not welcome here and are deleted by administrators, as you already have your user card attached to each answer.